# Macro too slow, is it a normal excel situation?

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone please tell me, why does this take forever :( I need to loop through like a whole year or two. I am simply taking the query from the cell and executing and writing back, let alone it goes (not responding) and making all other excel workbooks lag. THANKS FOR ANY ADVICE

```
Function getsqldata2(ByVal Query As String) As ADODB.Recordset

    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim server_name As String
    Dim database_name As String
    Dim user_id As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    'Establish connection to the database
    server_name = "AES-APP11"
    database_name = "v_mrf_4_Gen"
    user_id = "guest"    ' enter your user ID here
    password = "dcmguest"    ' Enter your password here
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open 'blablabla
    '----------------------------------------------------------------------
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rs = conn.Execute(Query)
    Set getsqldata2 = rs

End Function

Public Function findColumnNumber(ByVal strSearch As String) As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set aCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(" Status").Rows(4).Find(What:=strSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                                                                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                                                                                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        findColumnNumber = aCell.Column
    End If

End Function
Public Function IsoWeekNumber(InDate As Date) As Long
    IsoWeekNumber = DatePart("ww", InDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
End Function

Sub PDweekly()

    Dim I As Integer, j As Integer, n As Integer, m As Integer
    Dim Values(100, 10) As Integer
    Dim CountryCodes(100) As String
    Dim Data1(20) As String
    Dim EnvironmentMetaData(2 To 3) As String
    Dim t1, t2 As Double
    Dim Berk As String
    Dim NotrecordingTime As String
    Dim WeekNumber As Long
    Dim CurrentYear As Long
    Dim colName As String
    Dim colNumber As Long
    Dim WS_Count As Integer
    Dim ws As Integer
    Dim week As String
    Dim weekd As Integer
    Dim x As Date
    Dim yymmdd As Date
    Dim result As Object
    '---------------------------------------------------------

    currentdate = "2013-01-03"
    For weekd = 1 To 52
        yymmdd = currentdate

        WeekNumber = IsoWeekNumber(yymmdd)
        CurrentYear = Year(Date)
        If (WeekNumber < 10) Then
            colName = "w" + Right(CStr(CurrentYear), Len(CStr(CurrentYear)) - 2) + "0" + CStr(WeekNumber)
        Else
            colName = "w" + Right(CStr(CurrentYear), Len(CStr(CurrentYear)) - 2) + CStr(WeekNumber)
        End If

        colNumber = findColumnNumber(colName)
        If (Not colName = "w1353") Then


            For I = 8 To 89

                sqlstring = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(" Status").Cells(5, 3).Value
                cc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(" Status").Cells(I, 2).Value
                sqlstring = Replace(sqlstring, "Code", cc)
                sqlstring = Replace(sqlstring, "TODATE", CStr(yymmdd))

                Set result = getsqldata2(sqlstring)
                If (IsNull(result)) Then
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(" Status").Cells(I, colNumber) = result.Fields(0).Value = 0

                End If
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(" Status").Cells(I, colNumber) = result.Fields(0).Value
            Next I


            t2 = Timer
        End If
        currentdate = DateAdd("ww", 1, currentdate)
    Next weekd

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code seems to be performing quite a few iterations and connecting to the DB every time; so it does seem to be a pretty time-consuming process. A way to speed it up is letting the connection opened (suggestion written  in an answer right now); other way might be making the algorithm more efficient. Can you please, explain what you are trying to accomplish and what are the exact inputs/outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's most likely that SQL is slowing it down. Things that you can do.

- Open the connection outside the function, and don't close it until
  you're done.
- If you don't have an index on `Code`, create one.

If you really think it's Excel.

- Turn off `Application.ScreenUpdating`.
- Instead of updating once cell at a time, retrieve the whole grid as an array and loop/update the array and
  paste it back after you're done.

Comment: I did do the connection outside, and disabled screen updating. but damn my query takes ages ! am gonna see if one can help with that, it takes about 300 seconds nicely and am iterating like 500 times

Comment: and btw, when I create a connection outside, do I pass it or just use it anywhere in the app ? like my connectToDB app should return a connection type ?

Comment: It's a matter of style. Personally, I create a Connect function and call it from outside the loop.